# Magento 1.6 XML errors

Tags: xml, eclipse, magento, installation

I installed Magento. When I open it with eclipse or Zend Studio, it shows bunch of errors related to XML. I am not quite sure why it is happening. Anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Followings are the first few errors. But there are around 212 errors, and 1225 warnings.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
cvc-attribute.3: The value '{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding' of attribute 'name' on element 'binding' is not valid with respect to its type, 'NCName'.  wsdl.xml    /Magento/app/code/core/Mage/Api/etc line 111    XML Problem
cvc-attribute.3: The value '{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding' of attribute 'name' on element 'binding' is not valid with respect to its type, 'NCName'.  wsdl.xml    /Magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc line 956    XML Problem
cvc-attribute.3: The value '{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding' of attribute 'name' on element 'binding' is not valid with respect to its type, 'NCName'.  wsdl.xml    /Magento/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/etc    line 76 XML Problem
cvc-attribute.3: The value '{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding' of attribute 'name' on element 'binding' is not valid with respect to its type, 'NCName'.  wsdl.xml    /Magento/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc    line 571    XML Problem
cvc-attribute.3: The value '{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding' of attribute 'name' on element 'binding' is not valid with respect to its type, 'NCName'.  wsdl.xml    /Magento/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc    line 252    XML Problem
cvc-attribute.3: The value '{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding' of attribute 'name' on element 'binding' is not valid with respect to its type, 'NCName'.  wsdl.xml    /Magento/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/etc   line 64 XML Problem
cvc-attribute.3: The value '{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding' of attribute 'name' on element 'binding' is not valid with respect to its type, 'NCName'.  wsdl.xml    /Magento/app/code/core/Mage/GiftMessage/etc line 88 XML Problem
cvc-attribute.3: The value '{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding' of attribute 'name' on element 'binding' is not valid with respect to its type, 'NCName'.  wsdl.xml    /Magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc   line 871    XML Problem
cvc-attribute.3: The value '{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding' of attribute 'name' on element 'binding' is not valid with respect to its type, 'NCName'.  wsdl2.xml   /Magento/app/code/core/Mage/Api/etc line 167    XML Problem
cvc-attribute.3: The value '{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding' of attribute 'name' on element 'wsdl:binding' is not valid with respect to its type, 'NCName'. wsi.xml /Magento/app/code/core/Mage/Api/etc line 290    XML Problem
cvc-attribute.3: The value '{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding' of attribute 'name' on element 'wsdl:binding' is not valid with respect to its type, 'NCName'. wsi.xml /Magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc line 1531   XML Problem
cvc-attribute.3: The value '{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding' of attribute 'name' on element 'wsdl:binding' is not valid with respect to its type, 'NCName'. wsi.xml /Magento/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/etc    line 107    XML Problem
```

Thanks,

Comment: Having similar problem with CE 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not the complete answer to your problem:

- have you tried looking into *Window > Preferences > Validation* ?

I don't know what to touch exaclty to remove these errors and warnings.

Deactivating the XML validator should do the trick but I guess it's not acceptable as we want this validator running.

Maybe someone knows how to write a rule (*XML Validator > Settings > Add rule*) that will remove the errors.